# Task starting in UI context

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I have this piece of code to run a "heavy" Task asynchronously (and potentially show a result on the UI).
In my understanding, a new Task would always start in another context than the UI's. 
To test this I wrote the following code:

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Text = Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID.ToString();
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        label2.Text = Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID.ToString();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    });

    label2.Text = Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID.ToString();
}
```

I thought, that a Task (running in another context) cannot modify values in the UI context. Here this is done by the `label2.Text = Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID.ToString();` line inside the Task. And it works flawlessly. Also the `Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID` is the same inside the Task and outside. I also checked the current Thread (not shown in the code) and it was different inside the Task.

I think my understanding of Tasks is faulty.
Why is this Task started in same Context as the UI, even though it is running in a different Thread?

Comment: A separate thread can change stuff on the UI, but it's not threadsafe so it's really not guaranteed to work and can give unexpected behaviour. It does however, work sometimes. The correct way to do it is to call `BeginInvoke` on your form and do your updating in there.

Comment: @NibblyPig the part after the Task showed me the same Thread as before the Task. Changes made to the UI here should be threadsafe as I understand. Am I right?

Comment: From the information in the question I can deduce that you're talking about `SynchronizationContext` but why are you comparing the thread contexts when a thread context has nothing to do with the `SynchronizationContext` and mostly is used for remoting?

Comment: @Shoggomo The part after the task not necessarily will be in the same thread - depends on the current `SyncronizationContext` passed to the task which is typically derived from the calling thread. In case if initial thread is UI thread in vast majority of cases it will be the same thread after the task.

Answer (score 0):

From some basic testing it appears that the only reason your not getting a cross thread exception is that the text your placing in `label2` from another thread matches the text already present so no update is needed, in my case `Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID` was 0.

For example:

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Text = "Null";
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        label2.Text = SynchronizationContext.Current?.ToString() ?? "Null";
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    });

    label2.Text = "Done";
}
```

That code runs without exception, however, if we change the text:

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Text = SynchronizationContext.Current.ToString(); //WinForms Sync Context
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        label2.Text = SynchronizationContext.Current?.ToString() ?? "Null";
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    });

    label2.Text = "Done";
}
```

Now we get the cross thread, `InvalidOperationException`, as expected. So if we don't modify the value of the UI thread component no exception occurs, if we modify the value we get the expected exception.

Comment: You're right. This way i get a error. But only when I'm debugging. Strangely, if I run the same code in VS without debugging on it runs just fine. Are there some mechanics to mitigate such errors in production code?

Comment: General rule of thumb is not to update controls from background threads. If you need to report progress or other updates the recommended way is to inject an [`IProgress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) or just use `Invoke` on the control you need to update, e.g. `label2.Invoke(..)`